# Invalid argument error in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am running into the following problem. I don't know what i'm doing wrong. It shows me an error "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetString(int)' has some invalid arguments."

### Here is my code:

```
 SqlDataReader myReader;

      mycon.Open();
      myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
      while (myReader.Read())
         { 
          string cName = myReader.GetString("C_Name");

          textBox2.Text=cName;
         }
```

---

Comment: The error message even says to use an `int` :-)

Answer (score 3):

The `GetString` method only accepts an `int`. You're passing it a `string`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the parameter *(an integer)* represents "the zero-based column ordinal."

---

If `C_Name` is the first column *(for example)*, you'd want to call:

```
string cName = myReader.GetString(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned several times now, the signature of `GetString` requires an integer representing the column index.  You can translate the column name to its ordinal position using [`GetOrdinal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Therefore, you can get the string value of the `"C_NAME"` column by using `myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("C_NAME"))`.

`SqlDataReader` also [overrides the indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f01t4cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), which lets you write the same as `(string)myReader["C_Name"]`

Complete example:

```
var sqc = new SqlCommand("SELECT C_NAME from table", con);
using (var reader = sqc.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal("C_NAME");
        string byOrdinal = reader.GetString(ordinal);
        string byIndexer = (string)reader["C_NAME"];

        Console.Writeline("Column {0}, has the value of {1} (which is the same as {2})",
            ordinal, byOrdinal, byIndexer);
    }
}
```

You should also be careful to wrap your readers in `using` statements to ensure you don't leak database connections or run into a case where you consider enabling MARS.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the signature of [`GetString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetString(int)
```

It takes an integer ordinal (i.e. zero-based position) and you are trying to pass a string. There are no overloads which take a single string parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates, you are trying to use an overload of the `GetString` which does not exist.

You are passing a `string` argument, while the method is expecting an `integer` that represents the index of the requested column.

You can read more about the method in the [dcumetnation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Try changing your code to something like:

```
int indexOf cNameIdx = 5;// replace this with the real index from your select query
string cName = myReader.GetString(cNameIdx );
```